# Node translation syncing problem with entity references

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type with multilingual support (node translation). This content type also has an entity reference (module: `entityreference`) field.

My content is:

```
/node/1 English story 1
/node/2 French  story 1 (translation of #1)
/node/3 English story 2 with reference to #1
/node/4 French  story 2 (translation of #3) **entityreference problem here**
```

I've configured the reference to be synchronized. The problem is that whenever I translate or edit a node, it'll try to sync the reference to other translations.

So I'll always end up with:

```
#3 -> #1 (correct)
#4 -> #1 (wrong)
```

or:

```
#3 -> #2 (wrong)
#4 -> #2 (correct)
```

I can solve this by disabling syncing on the reference field but then I will have to be maintaining the references for all translations manually which is a problem in a website with many translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try module "Synchronize entity references" (`i18n_entityreference`) from project [Internationalization contributions](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n_contrib) (`i18n_contrib`). So far, for me it looks perfect. It even works with inline entity form widgets.

To install and use it:

1. **Install and enable the module.** If you use [`drush`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#readme):

   ```
   drush dl i18n_contrib && drush en i18n_entityreference
   ```

   (This requires the core module `i18n_sync` and will enable it automatically if not already done. It is needed for synchronizing field values across translations.)
2. **Configure "Synchronize translations"**. Basically go to "Structure → Content Types → [your content type]" in the admin menu, switch to tab "Synchronize translations", select your node reference field, and save. See [here for details](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279460).
3. **Use.** If you have existing content, the node reference field will be synced in a language-aware way when you save any node of a translation set for the next time.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out asap and get back to you. Wondering how it'll play together with https://www.drupal.org/project/cer

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, wrote this little workaround:

```
function YOURMODULE_i18n_sync_translation($entity_type, $translation, $translation_language, $source, $source_language, $field_names) {
  foreach ($field_names as $field_name) {
    $info = field_info_field($field_name);
    if ($info['type'] == 'entityreference') {
      $items = field_get_items($entity_type, $source, $field_name);
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $translations = translation_node_get_translations($item['target_id']);
        if (isset($translations[$translation_language])) {
          list($id, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, (object) $translations[$translation_language]);
          $translation->{$field_name}['und'][$delta]['target_id'] = $id;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note that it works well when changing the source node.

Answer (score 2):

There's a module for that: https://drupal.org/project/i18n_node_reference

> Provides i18n field synchronisation for a node_reference field.
>
> The referenced nodes are translated into the correct language. If no
>   such language exists, it is ignored. This is the same functionality as
>   is supported by the taxonomy reference translation in i18n_taxonomy.

Comment: I use the `entityreference` and not `references` module. So this doesn't apply in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet in the second answer won't work when editing the reference in a translation. That's because `translation_node_get_translations()` accepts a tnid as argument, not a nid. Check [the api docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_get_translations/7).

Change the call in the above code to something like this and it should work (for nodes only, in this case):

```
$referenced_node = node_load($item['target_id']);
$translations = translation_node_get_translations($referenced_node->tnid);
```

NOTE: I couldn't comment on the other answer, so i'm posting this one.