# Entity references linked to a wrong referent

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

On a Drupal 7 multilingual site, I have a content type containing a [field_group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) containing itself entity references fields.

I haven't enabled the i18n submodule "Synchronize translations" ("i18n_sync").

I have a content in French:

- contentFR

  - entityreferenceFR 1
  - entityreferenceFR 2

I want to translate this content in Italian, so I translate the entity references first, like this :

- entityreferenceIT 1 (translation of entityreferenceFR 1)
- entityreferenceIT 2 (translation of entityreferenceFR 2)

Then, I translate "contentFR" in Italian, and associate my 2 Italian entityreferences to this new Italian content, like this:

- contentIT (translation of contentFR)

  - entityreferenceIT 1
  - entityreferenceIT 2

Everything seems to go perfectly well, except that, when I go back to my French content, the references are the italian ones, like this:

- contentFR

  - entityreferenceIT 1
  - entityreferenceIT 2

If I edit again the French content to set the French references instead of the Italian ones, the switch happens again in the other way:

- contentIT

  - entityreferenceFR 1
  - entityreferenceFR 2

This is a live production site with 5 enabled languages. We've just enabled Italian and the issue exists only since then. Before, with other languages, everything was working well; the entity references were not linked to a wrong referent.

Also, I've seen this quite similar thread ([Node translation syncing problem with entity references](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31038/node-translation-syncing-problem-with-entity-references)) but:

- In my case, there's no synchronizing set on the reference field
- There wasn't any answer given in the original thread

The enabled i18 modules are: Block languages, Multilingual content, Multilingual select, Path translation, String translation, Taxonomy translation, Translation redirect, Translation sets, and Variable translation. The disabled modules are: Field translation and Synchronize translations.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to enable entity translation for this field; it can be done in the field UI, after installing the [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I want. I don't want per-field translation. I want my contents to be as independant as possible.

Comment: Are you sure i18n_contrib isn't enabled as well?